# What is the fastest method to parse XML?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

What is the fastest method(fastest performing) to parse an xml that is in a string, in Java platform ?

The file size can be around say 25kb.

The constraint is that I am not presented with an xml file, rather I have to parse the xml string !!

Comment: Your XML is invaid and does not display properly.

Comment: Also, what platform language/libraries are you using?

Comment: If your XML is really broken like that, then some kind of string matching might be the only way. But you're likely to have more problems. Please provide some more samples of the broken 'XML' so that there is more to work with.

Comment: Fastest to implement or best performing?

Comment: @Anand: Your XML is obviously not valid. As an advise, please fix it or people will complain about it, instead of answering to your real question :)

Comment: Give OP sometime to rephrase the question.

Comment: @Anand: your question has been reopened. Please fix your XML and post it again. After you paste it in, select the XML in the editor and press Control-K to format it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you have three options: [DOM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html), [SAX](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) and [StAX](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html). DOM is slower.

[StAX](http://stax.codehaus.org/Home) is said to provide "DOM ease with SAX efficiency". But in case the document you showed is the whole document - it really doesn't matter. The performance differences are important when working with larger files.

Answer (score 3):

You could build a DOM tree with the parsing result of your XML string. Here is a Java method to accomplish what you want:

```
private static Document ParseXMLString(String xmlString) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory fac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = fac.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
        Document doc = db.parse(inStream);
        return doc;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should apply to your case general concepts from *parsing theory*.

An explanation of complexity of the main parsing techniques is available [in this article](http://cslu.cse.ogi.edu/HLTsurvey/ch11node6.html).

Regarding Java, [here](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/16921) is a comparison among XML parser in Java by Sun, Oracle and Apache.

Reading from the abstract of the article:

> he XML parser world is a dynamic one.
>   As standards change, the parsers
>   change as well--XML parsers are
>   becoming more sophisticated. For most
>   programming projects, the parser, at
>   minimum, must support DOM Level 2, SAX
>   2, XSLT, and Namespaces. All the
>   parsers discussed here provide these
>   capabilities; however, there are
>   distinct differences in performance,
>   reliability, and conformance to
>   standards. In this article, I'll
>   compare the latest parsers from Sun,
>   Oracle, and the Apache Software
>   Foundation.

The rest of the analysis is available [here](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/16921).